# How to solve the python traceback error in execfile?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I found a code online, currently I am trying to start it. But I have some issues in running. If someone would help me, it would be great. Thank You.

```
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import random
import string
import re


chromeOptions = Options()
chromeOptions.headless = True #как будет запускаться хром - в фоне или нет
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(20) #количество одновременных потоков

def generate_random_string(length):
letters = string.ascii_lowercase
rand_string = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(length))
return rand_string

# простейшая функция выгрузки всех ссылок с заданой страницы
def getlinks(url):
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="the path", options=chromeOptions) # path к chromedriver
list = []
driver.get(url)
a = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a')
i = 0
for b in a:
i = i+1
link = b.get_attribute("href")
list.insert(i, link)
driver.quit()
return list

def scrape(url):
executor.submit(scraper, url)
executor.submit(scraper, a link/+generate_random_string(10))
#генерируем мусорные ссылки, если надо. кстати, если в тестируемом сайте есть функция поиска или любые другие страницы с тяжелыми запросами в БД, этот вариант - твой



def scraper(url):
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="the path", options=chromeOptions) #path к chromedriver
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(15)
driver.quit()

urls = getlinks("a link")
for url in urls * 10: #количество инстансов
scrape(url)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.2.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1483, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "D:\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.2.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/project/main.py", line 15
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
          ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Where (a link) is written must be a target link
and where (the path) it must be the path to chromedriver.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python uses indention to seperate code blocks. Each time a new scope is being entered, python interpreter expects an indented code block. This is how you should reformat your code. (Just to be sure I want to add that a proper selenium setup is required to run this code.)

```
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import random
import string
import re


chromeOptions = Options()
chromeOptions.headless = True #как будет запускаться хром - в фоне или нет
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(20) #количество одновременных потоков

def generate_random_string(length):
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    rand_string = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in 
    range(length))
    return rand_string

 # простейшая функция выгрузки всех ссылок с заданой страницы
def getlinks(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="the path", 
    options=chromeOptions)                         
 # path к chromedriver
    list = []
    driver.get(url)
    a = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a')
    i = 0
    for b in a:
        i = i+1
        link = b.get_attribute("href")
        list.insert(i, link)
    driver.quit()
    return list

def scrape(url):
    executor.submit(scraper, url)
    executor.submit(scraper, a link/+generate_random_string(10))
#генерируем мусорные ссылки, если надо. кстати, если в тестируемом сайте         
#есть функция поиска или любые другие страницы с тяжелыми запросами в БД,                 
#этот вариант - твой



def scraper(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="the path", 
    options=chromeOptions)         
    #path к chromedriver
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(15)
    driver.quit()

urls = getlinks("a link")
for url in urls * 10: #количество инстансов
    scrape(url)
```